# Sencha Touch selectfield change event not working with different value but same text

Tags: sencha-touch-2

The selectfield change event not working with different value but same text.
Demo here:- https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jat

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Select',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    label: 'Choose one',
                    options: [
                        {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
                        {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
                        {text: 'Second Option',  value: 'third'}
                    ],
                    listeners:{
                        change:function(selectfield,newValue,oldValue,eOpts){
                            alert(newValue);
                        }
                    }

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Hello, I think you should fix formatting of your code, and add a question, there is none yet.

Comment: What is the meaning of keeping two fields with same test??

Comment: i need that for my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setValue: function(newValue) {
    var oldValue = this._value;

    this.updateValue(this.applyValue(newValue));

    newValue = this.getValue();
    //alert(newValue)
    if (this.initialized) {
        this.onChange(this, newValue, oldValue);
    }

    return this;
}
```

this is the working solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Input.js file in source codes

```
setValue: function(newValue) {

    var oldValue = this._value;

    this.updateValue(this.applyValue(newValue));

    newValue = this.getValue();

    **if (String(newValue) != String(oldValue) && this.initialized) {
        this.onChange(this, newValue, oldValue);
    }**

    return this;
}
```

Comment: thanks sargis for pointing me in right direction i posted my answer below.i just remove String(newValue) != String(oldValue) && from if statement.it's working now.Thanks.